# Spring Injection + JSF + Hibernate

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm actually starting with JSF, so go easy.

I'm trying to mix Spring 3.x + Hibernate 4 + JSF 2.2
I used to mix Spring + Hibernate in Desktop applications, and that wasn't a problem at all.

But now, I'm a little confused here.
I'm trying to map through annotations and I'm pretty sure that is a mess.

First of all, I'd like to ask you the best practice to Integrate all those technologies and keep the MVC pattern

That being said, here are my files:

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>WebCD</display-name>
    <!-- Spring Config -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

### faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

### AppMainController.java

```
@Controller
public class AppMainController {
@Autowired
    private CDDao                       cdDao;

    public List<CD> findAllCDs() throws SQLException {
        List<CD> cds = cdDao.findAll();
        return cds;
    }
}
```

### CDDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class CDDaoImpl extends Dao<CD> implements CDDao {

    @Override
    public Class<CD> getEntityClass() {
        return CD.class;
    }

}
```

### And, finally, the *.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Lista de CDs</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <center>
        <h1>Lista de CDS</h1>
    </center>
    <h:messages />
    <h:dataTable value="#{/*Right here I really don't know what to call*/.findAllCDs()}" var="cd"
        rules="rows" cellpadding="5">
        <f:facet name="caption">Essa é a lista de todos os CD's cadastrados no sistema</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="header">Lista de CD's</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="footer">Fim da Lista de CD's</f:facet>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Código</f:facet>
#{cd.id}
</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Descrição</f:facet>
#{cd.descricao}
</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Gravadora</f:facet>
#{cd.fkLabel}
</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Preço</f:facet>
#{cd.preco}
</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data Compra</f:facet>
#{cd.dataCompra}
</h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Data Gravação</f:facet>
#{cd.dataGravacao}
</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I've tried these approaches:

- Add `@ManagedBean(name="ctrl")` to the `AppMainController` and call `ctrl.findAllCDs()`.
- Create a property `private List<CD> cds` and a method calling `cdDao.findAll()` to fill the list and retrieve to the dataTable as `myBean.cds`.

These were the following exceptions:

- `NullPointerException`: cdDao was null at some points, which leads me to consider the only logical inference: `cdDao` is not being injected (Autowired)
- `@ManagedBean` was not in the right place..

I'd be grateful if you could show me a guideline, a path, because I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing `@ManagedBean` for `@Named("name")` and `@Autowired` for `@Inject`, the problem was solved.

Comment: Why are you installing Spring if you have apparently no idea what it's to be used for?

Comment: Because it's a personal project, and your question is not only pointless but also makes no sense. Just because I don't know how to use it WITH JSF, it doesn't mean that I won't try and learn.

Comment: @kolossus thank you for the explanation. Will be very useful in the future.